# How can I display a warning message on textfield in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-components

I'm new to Yii framework and I need to display the validation error message as in login form `"Username cannot be blank"`. Now, I have a text field where I updated the fields and the during validation I want a message to be displayed. How can I do this?

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    // set the parameters for the bizRule
    $params = array('GroupzSupport'=>$model);
    // now check the bizrule for this user
    if (!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', $params) &&
        !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'))
    {
        throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not authorized to perform this action');
    }
      else
    {

       if(isset($_POST['GroupzSupport']))
        {                        

           $password_current=$_POST['GroupzSupport']['password_current'];   
           $pass=$model->validatePassword($password_current);

            $model->attributes=$_POST['GroupzSupport'];
                        if($pass==1)
                        {
                        $model->password = $model->hashPassword($_POST['GroupzSupport']['password_new']);
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('/messageTemplate/admin'));
                        }
                        else {$errors="Incorrect Current password"; print '<span style="color:red"><b>';
print '</b><b>'.$errors;
print '</b></span>';}
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'password-recovery-reset-password-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>


    <div class="row"><?php 
        echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); 
        echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
        echo $form->error($model,'username'); 
    ?></div>


<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'current password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password_current',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>30)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_current'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'new password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'password_new',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>30)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_new'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'confirm new password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password_repeat',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>30)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_repeat'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons"><?php 
        echo CHtml::submitButton('Reset Your Password');
        ?></div><?php

$this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Now currently I'm displaying it at the top.
[image]

I want to display it right on the textfield as in login page.   [image]  How can I do this?

Comment: can you clarify what you want? do you want the error to be displayed on the right hand side of the text field, or inside the text field, or something else?

Comment: I want error to be displayed on the text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before redirect, add the message to the desired field.

In the model Validator:

**$this->addError('field_name', "Message error.");**

Or in Controller action:

**$model->addError('field_name', "Message error.");**

Comment: `<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'current password'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password_current',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>30)); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_current'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->addError('password_current', "Message error.");?>
 </div>`
        I did this but I get an exception - do not have a method or closure named "addError".

Comment: Edited. You are doing this on Controller, not in the model. Replace $this for $model

Comment: Update your question code, please. o see how you are doing right now.